# Как в Wordpress сделать мультиязычными статичные элементы прописанные в html?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как в Wordpress сделать мультиязычными статичные элементы прописанные в html?
Например :

```
    <h1>Привет</h1>.
```

Я так понимаю Polylang тут не поможет.Можно ли вручную как-то сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я так понимаю Polylang тут не поможет.

Поможет.

`if pll_current_language` и далее по необходимости.

Или зарегистрировать нужны строки `pll_register_string` и вывести их  `pll_e`

См
https://polylang.pro/doc/developpers-how-to/
https://polylang.pro/doc/function-reference/

Answer (score 3):

Это делается через gettext функции. Хорошее описание на русском [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function-cat/lokalizatsiya).

В вашем примере код должен выглядеть так:

```
<h1><?php echo __('Привет', 'my_text_domain'); ?></h1>
```

Дальше надо воспользоваться poedit, чтобы автоматически собрать все строки в вашем коде. Инструкция на руском [здесь](https://wpmag.ru/2013/kak-perevodit-temyi-wordpress/).

Потом скомпилировать .po в .mo, добавить в тему или плагин.

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто, я делаю это так.

```html
<h1>
  <?php
    if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='ru'){
    ?>
    Привет
    <?php }elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){
    ?>
    Hello
    <?php
    }
  ?> 
</h1>
```